# Check if characters after delimiter exist in Python

Tags: python, parsing

Suppose I have a file that contains multiple lines such as:

```
getIPAddress(): 1231.124131.32
getTime(): 1:11
getYear(): 2015
```

and I wanted to simply check whether or not characters exist after the :  I have thought about splitting it based on the ":", but in the case that it is something like this:

```
getYear(): 
getTime(): 1:11
```

if I split getYear() based on the ":" and try to access the second element of the list, it would return  a null. How exactly can I approach this situation successfully? Ideally, wouldn't want to use a try/catch if possible.

Right now, I have something like this:

```
                        newline = line.split(":",1)[1]
```

For some reason, even if there is no information after the colon, so like for `getYear():` 
this does not go into my except IndexError case. Does anyone know why this works? I'm pretty confused as to how it's not returning an indexerror.

Comment: To answer your question "Does anyone know why this works?": because it would return "getYear():" splitted as ["getYear()",""], so a second element exists but it's an empty string, no exceptionis raised.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it in an interactive session and see what gets returned:

```
>>> "foo:".split(":")
['foo', '']
```

As long as the colon is present, `line.split(":", 1)` will always return a two-element list. Only if it's omitted entirely will it return length 1.

One way to do what you're looking for is:

```
parts = line.split(":", 1)
if len(parts) >= 2 and parts[1]: # len can't actually exceed 2 but it's a good habit to check
    # characters are present after the first colon
```

Or, as shx2 pointed out, partition - that will always give you a three-element response, of which the last consists of any characters present after the first colon.

Comment: If you want to allow for the future possibility that the number of split parts might be increased, wouldn't it be better to use `parts[-1]`?

Comment: Sure, that would work too. Although it's moot as long as you're specifying the maximum number of splits, which I did since the sample data includes ":" in the time.

Answer (score 1):

If your string contains N colons, spliting it on colon will **always** return a list of length N+1. Some of the "split" elements may be empty strings, as in your case.  This differentiates spliting a string like `getYear()` from a string like `getYear():`.

You can either check if the value of `tokens[1]` is empty, or use [`partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition), and check the 3rd value returned by it.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the `getSomething()` and the data behind the `:` by using a regex in combination with matching groups:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import re

preg = re.compile('^(?P<get_sth>.*):{1}\s{1}(?P<data>.*)$')

with open('foo.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = preg.match(line)
        if m:
            print(m.group('get_sth'), m.group('data'))
```

Where `foo.txt` is like the follwowing:

```
getIPAddress(): 1231.124131.32
getTime(): 1:11
getYear(): 2015
```

And the output given by the `print` statement is:

```
getIPAddress() 1231.124131.32
getTime() 1:11
getYear() 2015
```

Comment: Overkill for this situation IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic, It might help. There are some library functions you could use to check for any character as well.

```
myString = "Position of a character"
    len2 = myString.index(':')
    //Then check from len2+1 to the lenght of the string for any character.
    //if there is any character use it for processing, other wise ignore.
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` will split the string and return an empty string for the second element in the list if nothing is after the colon or a string with whitespace characters if there are any present.

```
string1 = "something: "
string2 = "something:"
string3 = "something:\n"
string1.split(":")
Out: ['something', ' ']
string2.split(":")
Out: ['something', '']
string3.split(":")
Out: ['something', '\n']
```

You could use regex to check if there is anything other than whitespace after the colon

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r':\s*\S')
def line_checker(text):
    if regex.search(text):
        return True
    else:
        return False
line_checker(string1)
Out: False
line_checker(string2)
Out: False
line_checker(string2)
Out: False
line_checker("something:  123.479")
Out: True
```

In this regex the `\s*` will match 0 or more whitespace characters that come after the colon and the `\S` will match anything that is not whitespace, so you will only get a match if there is something other than whitespace.